# VBA - best way of storing value from cell whose value will change

Tags: vba, storing-data

I have a formula in cell b2 which will change based on inputs from a macro. What's the best way of storing the value from b2 at a certain point in time?

The macro will be called multiple times and I don't know if it's possible storing the value (from that single point in time) as a variable without it getting overwritten every single time the macro is called. I have the value stored in a cell, wondering if there's a better way...

```
'stores index value 
If IsEmpty(Sheet30.Range("AU9")) = False Then
Else
    Sheet30.Range("AU9").Value = Sheet30.Range("b2")
End If
'followed by code that changes the value of cell b2
```

This is how I'm storing my value, in the actual spreedsheet. Again, the macro will be called multiple times by the user, and I want to store the first iterated value of b2. Is there a more efficient way?

EDIT:
I modified Mukul's answer so it can be called more than once.

```
Public Sub PreserveFirstValue(n as variant, o as range, p as boolean)
  If Not p Then
   If isnumeric(o.value) then
    n = o.value
    p = True
   End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any existing code for us to work with?

Comment: Do you need to store the history just internally in your code while it's running, or do you need to store it permanently? If you need to store it permanently you'd need to write it to another sheet or range with a datestamp

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid permanently. would you store it to a cell like in my edit?

Comment: That will only store the last value and overwrite it each time. Is that what you want? or do you want to store every historical value?

Comment: No, I wish to store the very first value.

Comment: So at any time you need to know two values: the very first value, and the current value? The first value being the value when you open the workbook?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a module to the workbook and declare a public Boolean value and a public variable to preserve the old value.
2. Preserve the value of the cell as soon as workbook is opened (i.e. Private Sub Workbook_Open() event) or where you feel its good time to preserve the value of the cell in the code you are doing it now.

Code is shown below:-

```
'Place below statement where you want to preserve the value
Call PreserveFirstValue() 'add this line to preserve the value


'Module Code is below
Public HasPreservedValue As Boolean
Public OldValue As String

Public Sub PreserveFirstValue()
  If Not HasPreservedValue Then
    OldValue = Sheet30.Range("b2").Text
    HasPreservedValue = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you take a look at my edit? I get a mismatch error when I run it in some cases, but seems to work for the most part...

Comment: Its difficult to locate the error in your function. As error is "mismatch error", I would replace single with Variant and try. `Public Sub PreserveFirstValue(n as Variant, o as range, p as boolean)`